# Can I get a Kodachrome-film look in my digital photos after editing?

Tags: editing

Can I edit my digital photos so they will get the colors and the values of the famous Kodachrome film or at least resemble to it? I can also ask the futile question edit the photos so they have a Leica look?

Comment: Related: [Slides in the digital era](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/119634/15871)

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate target color profiles to alter an image to look like other known profiles. You can do this manually or you can leverage profiles developed by other people. You'll have more flexibility editing RAW than JPG.

For example: [Classic K14 Lightroom Preset](https://theclassicpresets.com/pages/about-the-classic-k14)

I used to shoot a lot of Kodachrome. When the shot was right it could be fabulous, but it was contrasty and intolerant of exposure error and dynamic range.

Kodachrome still has a warm place in my heart, but Digital Rules!